# Why is systemctl showing memory current as [Not Set]?

Tags: bash, firefox, systemd, memory-usage

I have been trying to limit the memory usage of firefox, by following this tutorial: https://dev.to/msugakov/taking-firefox-memory-usage-under-control-on-linux-4b02

In there, we limit the memory usage of Firefox by using systemd

```
systemd-run --unit=my-firefox --user --scope -p MemoryHigh=6G -p MemoryMax=7G -p MemorySwapMax=0 firefox
```

And then check memory usage by systemctl

```
systemctl --user show my-firefox.scope | grep Memory
```

Unfortunately, in my case, I get not set in MemoryCurrent, something like this output below:

```
$ systemctl --user show limited-firefox.scope | grep Memory
MemoryCurrent=[not set]
EffectiveMemoryNodes=
AllowedMemoryNodes=
MemoryAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryLow=0
DefaultMemoryMin=0
MemoryMin=0
MemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=2147483648
MemoryMax=3221225472
MemorySwapMax=0
MemoryLimit=infinity
```

Is there something I am missing, or wrong with my system?